# Why does this code work in repl.it but not in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, discrete-mathematics

I know this isn't the best-looking code but it is meant for a discrete math assignment, so I just coded it up real quick.

Anyways, for some reason when I calculate permutations with no repetition it only gives me 1 on VS but when I run the same code on repl.it it gives me the correct answer.

```
int main()
{
    // Instance Variables
    unsigned int n, r;
    int input;
    long answer;
    bool repitAllow, ordered;

    /******************** INPUTS ***********************/

    // Get the integers from user
    cout << "Enter an integer greater than 0 for r: ";
    cin >> input;
    // Check input is valid
    if (input < 1)
    {
        cerr << "r must be greater than 0!";
        return 1;
    }
    // Set r to input from user
    r = input;

    cout << "Enter an integer for n that is >= r: ";
    cin >> input;
    // Check input is valid
    if (input < r)
    {
        cerr << "n must be greater than r!";
        return 2;
    }
    // set n equal to input
    n = input;

    // Ask if repition is allowed.
    cout << "Is repition allowed? (1 = yes) (0 = no): ";
    cin >> input;

    // Check for validity
    if (input < 0 || input > 1)
    {
        cerr << "Please enter a valid input!";
        return 3;
    }

    // Assign bool from selection for if repition is allowed
    repitAllow = (input == 1) ? true : false;

    // Ask if order matters
    cout << "Does order matter? (1 = yes) (0 = no): ";
    cin >> input;

    // Check for validity
    if (input < 0 || input > 1)
    {
        cerr << "Please enter a valid input!";
        return 4;
    }

    // Assign bool from selection for if order matters
    ordered = (input == 1) ? true : false;


    /******************** CALCULATIONS ***************************/

    if (ordered) // Calculate permutations
    {
        if (repitAllow)
        {
            answer = pow(n, r);
        }
        else // Repition not allowed
        {
            answer = factorial(n) / factorial((n - r));
        }
    }
    else // Calculate combinations
    {
        if (repitAllow)
        {
            answer = factorial(r + n - 1) / (factorial(r) * factorial((n - 1)));
        }
        else // Repition not allowed
        {
            answer = factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * factorial(n - r));
        }
    }


    /******************** OUTPUT *******************/
    if (!ordered)
        cout << "\nThat gives you " << answer << " combinations.\n\n";
    else
        cout << "\nThat gives you " << answer << " permutations.\n\n";
}

/*********************************************
*   FUNCTIONS:
*********************************************/
/**DESCRIPTION: <function description> */
//function definition

// Calculate factorials
long factorial(int x)
{
    long factorial = 1;

  // Loop to create factorial for x
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        factorial *= i;

    return factorial;
}
```

**Output from repl.it:**

Enter an integer greater than 0 for r: *3* 
Enter an integer for n that is >= r: *16* 
Is repition allowed? (1 = yes) (0 = no): *0* 
Does order matter? (1 = yes) (0 = no): *1*

That gives you 3360 permutations.

**Output from VS:**

Enter an integer greater than 0 for r: *3* 
Enter an integer for n that is >= r: *16* 
Is repition allowed? (1 = yes) (0 = no): *0* 
Does order matter? (1 = yes) (0 = no): *1*

That gives you 1 permutations.

Comment: At the computation step, are the values of n and r what you expect them to be?  Are calls to `factorial()` returning the correct results?  Is the correct computation line chosen?  You can answer these questions using your debugger, or just add additional `cout` statements.

Comment: Is your VS build set to target 64-bit architecture?  Note that 16! is too large to fit in a 32-bit word.  Switching your `long`s to `long long`s could also help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is your VS build set to target 64-bit architecture? Note that 16! is
> too large to fit in a 32-bit word. Switching your longs to long longs
> could also help. –  0x5453

Thank you! Setting `long` to `long long` fixed the problem.